# I/O Resource Plan

Tags: oracle

My 10g DB is acting as a data warehouse store and is very busy. 
I know that it's possible to set limits on CPU consumption ratios between users so that certain users will be prioritized. However, in my case the IO is the "expensive" resource, not CPU.
Is it possible to manage and set priorities on IO?

Thanks

p.s.
I saw that one can use a profile to set IO limits, but I think this isn't suitable for me because the limits actually cause the query to be canceled if the limit is reach, and this is too far.

Comment: +1 I looked at this a while back and didn't find much available for 10g.

Answer (score 2):

Basic [PROFILE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6010.htm#SQLRF01310) management doesn't allow you to set fine-tuned priorities. There is another tool in the database however that may be suitable for what you want to achieve: the [Database Resource Manager](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/dbrm001.htm#sthref2340).

I have not used this tool yet, but this blog post ["Oracle Database Resource Manager and Oracle Application Express"](http://joelkallman.blogspot.com/2009/08/oracle-database-resource-manager-and.html)(by the guy behind [apex.oracle.com](http://apex.oracle.com)) looks like a good example. Perhaps you can use something similar to implement your priority strategy.

Comment: I don't believe I/O is one of the resources you can control with this tool, at least in 10g. I seem to have heard something about it coming in 11g.

Comment: I will give you +1 for the blog pointer, though - a good example of resource manager usage.

Comment: Does anyone know if 11g has this capability?